# Sorting 2D array of Int in Swift

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, swift4

I'm trying to sort array like this one `[[Int]]` of 6 rows and 6 columns with sorted(by: `{ $0[0] < $1[0] }`).
But sorted array is sorted only by the first number in a row!
This is example source array:

> 5;8;1;13;2;6
>
> 20;8;19;12;41;13
>
> 23;14;15;36;7;18
>
> 9;27;21;12;3;44
>
> 25;16;7;18;9;30
>
> 1;32;13;34;25;45

And this is what I've got after sorting:

> 1;32;13;34;25;45
>
> 5;8;1;13;2;6
>
> 9;27;21;12;3;44
>
> 20;8;19;12;41;13
>
> 23;14;15;36;7;18
>
> 25;16;7;18;9;30
>
> I don't need row's order to be changed. I need to get something like
>   that:
>
> 1;2;5;6;8;13
>
> 8;12;13;19;20;41
>
> 7;14;15;18;23;36
>
> 3;9;12;21;27;44
>
> 7;9;16;18;25;30
>
> 1;13;25;32;34;45

[Here](http://%20https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhHaB.jpg) is my sample output.
I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to value semantics you have to `map` the array to its sorted content

```
let array = [[5,8,1,13,2,6],
             [20,8,19,12,41,13],
             [23,14,15,36,7,18],
             [9,27,21,12,3,44],
             [25,16,7,18,9,30],
             [1,32,13,34,25,45]]

let sortedArray = array.map{ $0.sorted() }
print(sortedArray)
```